# How to read comments using StAX parser event reader api

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

I am parsing `xml` files using `StAX` parser event reader api.
I could find methods to read start, end elements but could not find
methods to read comments.

I could find a way to read comments using stream reader api of `StAX` parser, but I need it using event reader api.

```
case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
     StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
     String startTag = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
     break;
case XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT :
     ????
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `String s = event.toString();` though then you will get full comment `<!-- text -->`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting the commented line as <!-- text -->